# Link to rate my application is not working in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an IPhone application in which i am using this link as to rate my application in the itunes.`http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=blabla&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software`.working fine in the mac,but in ipad and iphone showing cannot connect.can anybody help me?have tried this also `http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=blabla&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8`.

Comment: see this [a site](http://iostipsntricks.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/how-to-get-people-to-rate-your-ios-app/), it may help you.

Comment: @Tejeshwar it's not a bug. You somehow expect the iPhone to open absolute iTunes links that were never supported.  You're attempting to do something that isn't allowed, hence it doesn't work.

Comment: @CodaFi i had done this with my earlier apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=BLABLAH
```

Although, [I think this no longer works in iOS6](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate/issues/38). Some people report:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/LANGUAGE/app/idAPP_ID
```

But I have never tried it and it may change before the official release.

Answer (score 0):

I am not hundred percent sure but it may an issue that your iTunes Store Country is different from our iPhone,iPad. I can't say but is your app is country specific ? If it is then please check your AppStore country in device.

Comment: it was a universal app.there is no pbm with that,my device is i think in indian store.

Comment: and what's your iTunes store ?